# Subversion find tag by part of its name (on windows)

Tags: php, windows, svn, tags, cmd

How do I find tag by part of its name?

I have structure on repository

/trunk
/tags
   /Revert
   /86__20140206_123000
   /85__20140205_123000
   /{rev_no}{2x_}{YYYYMMHH}{1x_}{HHiiss}

I am working on revert procedure: Trunk is faulty, so php script will do:
1. copy /tags/Revert tag to /trunk
2. copy tag with top number of revision no to /tags/Revert
3. remove copied in point 2. tag

So the next commit (via php) will be:
1. copy /tags//Revert to /tags/{rev_no}{2x__}{now_date_time} tag
2. copy /trunk to Revert tag
3. put (copy from dev branch) the new staff to /trunk/

Creating, removing, copying works fine. 
The only problem is that I need to find (on windows) tag to copy to Revert, base only on part of its name: I have {rev_no}{2x_*}


svn copy [repo]/tags/ | find "86*_*" /. [repo]/trunk
gives as result: File not found - "86__*"/;

In fact I tried many option, but all failed and now running out of ideas.


I am issuing those commands via php execute, so I think I need to try single command to capture tag name and next command to copy its content to trunk.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you hear about `svn ls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preface

OMFG!

- **Who invented such idiotic restore-policy for SVN-repository?**

  1. Undo revisions in natural, brain-powered way performed by reverse-merge bad revisions (to "Last-Known-Good")
  2. **Single** Last-Known-Good may be stored as custom svn-property inside trunk instead of cluttering of tags
- **Who invented such brainless naming for tags?**

Tags (and any other node) per se contain all needed data, reachable by `svn ls` or `svn log` (src, src rev, timestamp of creating)

If you want to eliminate future headaches for all, best choice will be re-design **all from scratch** (see my notes 1-2 above)

### Face

> The only problem is that I need to find (on windows) tag to copy to Revert

If revision is leading part of tag-name and because Windows `sort` it worse than terrible, you must to rename all tags and add leading zeroes for correct **numerical sorting**, without it sort will give you something like

```
/125__20140207_123000
/85__20140203_123000
/86__20140204_123000
/99__20140205_123000
```

or, with thousands in set

```
/125__20140207_123000
/4025__20140307_123000
/85__20140203_123000
/86__20140204_123000
/99__20140205_123000
```

contrary to

```
/0085__20140203_123000
/0086__20140204_123000
/0099__20140205_123000
/0125__20140207_123000
/4025__20140307_123000
```

in any case, list of all existing tags is `svn ls URL`. AFAICR (TBT!!!), newest tags are always on bottom, regardless of name

```
> svn ls http://websvn.tigris.org/svn/websvn/tags
1.00/
1.01/
1.02/
...
2.3.3/
```

you can use tag-name from last line and combine URL, or use `svn ls -v`

```
>svn ls -v http://websvn.tigris.org/svn/websvn/tags
   1268 dirkthom              июн 27  2011 ./
      2 tarmes                фев 04  2004 1.00/
      7 tarmes                фев 05  2004 1.01/
     14 tarmes                фев 06  2004 1.02/
    ...
   1268 dirkthom              июн 27  2011 2.3.3/
```

and find freshest tag (last column) by max revision in first column (`1268 dirkthom              июн 27  2011 2.3.3/`) or use svn log for tags, only for latest revision, with filelist, and get last tag as part of affected files

```
>svn log -l 1 http://websvn.tigris.org/svn/websvn/tags -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1268 | dirkthomas | 2011-06-27 15:12:51 +0600 (Пн, 27 июн 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /package.cmd
   M /package.sh
   A /tags/2.3.3 (from /branches/2.3:1266)
   ...
```

`A /tags/2.3.3` will identify for you latest tag